# (GCP) API keys. Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, android-security

Getting error when uploading build in google play store console. The error is following.

Leaked GCP API Keys
Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys.

The culprit code is following.

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.GOOGLE_API_KEY);
```

According to the documentation i am reading key from BuildConfig and also restrict the key. But still the same issue. how can i fix this issue..

Comment: The [manual says](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711?hl=en) "Please Note: If you have already added restrictions to your API key, you can ignore this warning." But at the same time, it says the warning cannot be ignored. Stupid Google.

Comment: Have you really done what's on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys#adding_android_restrictions)? Have you pinned your key to your app?

Comment: @DanielW. yes i did this.

Answer (score 21):

I also faced the same problem. I couldn't find any proper solution for this. After lot of searching I found a solution. So I am giving a complete guide for this issue.
Many thanks to **Prasenjit Banerjee** for helping me.

Complete guide for use API Keys and avoid **Leaked GCP API Keys** security issue in Google Play Console :

1. First of all you need to follow [API security best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restrict_apikey) for add restrictions and securely using API keys.
2. Then follow [Set Up an Android Studio Project](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#step_2_add_your_api_key_to_the_project) for add API keys to `local.properties` and use them in `AndroidManifest.xml` & Main program.
3. Finally access API keys As a variable in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```xml
<application>
        .
        .
        .
        .        
        <activity>
            .
            .
            .
            .
        </activity>
  
    <meta-data
        android:name = "keyValue"
        android:value = "${KEY}"/>
      
</application>
```

4. Access API keys in `MainActivity.kt` and type in the below code to get the KEY value from the meta-data in `AndroidManifest.xml` (Find solution from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-hide-api-and-secret-keys-in-android-studio/) in **GeeksforGeeks** ) :

    
   **Note:** Don't use `BuildConfig` class to get these API keys because this class expose those properties as variables.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //get the KEY value from the meta-data in AndroidManifest
        val ai: ApplicationInfo = applicationContext.packageManager
            .getApplicationInfo(applicationContext.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        val value = ai.metaData["keyValue"]
        val key = value.toString()

        //for testing only
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        // use this key to initialize places sdk
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful, we've been struggling with this message in several updates, thanks Milan!

Comment: How can we handle different keys for different flavors any recommendation for doing that?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this achieves? All I see is that you moved the API key from one publicly accessible place to another. Accessing Manifest entries is as trivial as reading BuildConfig variables.

Comment: This solution is also not safe. Android Manifest meta-data values can potentially be accessed by other apps on the device.

Comment: Good one. but how can i maintain dev, prod keys

Comment: According to the [secrets-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin) document, you can set build-variant specific properties (build type or flavor), create a properties file at the root directory of the project with the same name as the variant. For example, to set keys specific for the `release` build type, create a new file called `release.properties` containing release-specific keys. @HamidJaved @Amal

Answer (score 1):

In order to secure your API Keys in GCP you have to search for "Credentials" in the Cloud Platform Console. Create a new API Key using the Create credentials button, configured the same as the compromised API Key. The restrictions on the API Key must match, otherwise you may suffer an outage.

Push the API Key to all locations in which the old key was in use, and then delete the old key.

---

I would recommend you to take a look at the official documentation for handing [compromised credentials in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/security/compromised-credentials) for a better detail.

Other than that, you might want to consider [Keyless API authentication](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-workload-identity-pools-providers) by [leveraging workload identify federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/how-to#using-workload-identity-federation)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to get GCP Key from local properties directly from BuildConfig. I fixed it by getting the key from application metadata by using this extension function

```kotlin
fun Context.getKey(): String {
    val applicationInfo = packageManager
        .getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    val keyValue = applicationInfo.metaData?.get("com.google.android.geo.API_KEY")
    return keyValue.toString()
}
```

So when you want to get the key you can use

1. Fragment

```kotlin
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), requireContext().getKey());
```

2. Activity

```kotlin
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), this.getKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

What [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71155071/8382008) is about is basically available with gradle secrets plugin as descibred in the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin

Also, keep in mind that when you get an error about exposed api keys on pre-launch reports, or you see a warning after review, you can simply ignore this warning after you take the steps described in the documentation ([restricting API](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys) + [gradle plugin secrets](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin)). This warning won't disappear, but it won't block you from publishing your app.