# Leaked GCP API Keys Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details

Tags: java, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eq0p.png)

I have used API_KEY="my_api_key" in gradle.properties file and added buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY) to app/gradle file and define
private static final String API_KEY = BuildConfig.API_KEY; to activity class and initiliized on create method Places.initialize(this, API_KEY);

I have tried to concate string also but same issue.
I restricted my API also in google console by adding SHA keys for both debug and release but still the same issue

Comment: Please try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71155071/8752580. This is an updated solution.